# How to create a defined structured metadata to use?

Tags: python, metadata

I started learning python and trying to read a log file having a defined structure

```
12 34 20 02 02 14 15 10 03 02 03 0A 00 02 60 17 0A 80 0B 00 01 72 0B 80 0C 00 01 45 0C 80
56 78 20 02 02 14 15 10
```

The data can be decoded as:

```
12 34                   --> First file number (2 bytes)
20 02 02 14 15 10       --> file written date (6 bytes)
03 02                   --> File Id
03                      --> No of files

0A 00   --> sub file number 1 start
02      --> length of the file
20 07   --> data in the file
0A 80   --> sub file number 1 end

0B 00   --> sub file number 2 start
01      --> length of the file
72      --> data in the file
0B 80   --> sub file number 2 end

0C 00   --> sub file number 3 start
01      --> length of the file
45      --> data in the file
0C 80   --> sub file number 3 end


56 78               --> Second file number (2 bytes)
20 02 02 14 15 10   --> file written date (6 bytes)
.......
........
...
```

Based on the "No of Files" value = 3, the next 3 sections shall be 3 chunks of data with Start, length, data inside the file and the end value.

After this section, again another section with similar structure data shall be available.

I tried reading byte by byte, but thought that it can be defined properly and being beginner, trying to learn python more.

```
# First file number
byte = file.read(2)
hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
print("First File number      : %s" %(codecs.decode(hexadecimal, "hex").decode('ascii')))

# code for date

# First file Id
byte = file.read(2)
hexadecimal = binascii.hexlify(byte)
print("First File Id      : %s" %(codecs.decode(hexadecimal, "hex").decode('ascii')))
```

How can this be written in a better way? Also, if I write this logic in another file, by passing file as input argument, all the details shall be fetched in a tuple or dict?

Comment: Why does first file have **three** "sub file number 1"s? Also what exactly is a "defined structured metadata"?

Comment: Your example does not match the line from the log file you provided.

Comment: @martineau: entire data is in one file, but in sequential way. No of files = 3, says the next 3 sections after this value has info about the 3 files.(sub file start, length, data and end of file address) Defined Structured metadata : First file number (2 bytes), file written date (6 bytes), File Id,  No of files, based on No of files value, the next section shall be sub-section * no of files information.Followed by that again , Second file number (2 bytes), file written date (6 bytes), File Id,  No of files, and so on

Comment: @James: Only the first byte is incorrect in my example, as I typed as I was calculating little endian format.The rest looks fine ?

Comment: Just repeating what's already in your question doesn't help. What I asked was if the "No of files" is 3, why do the next three sections each repeatedly say "sub file number 1 start" instead of "sub file number 1 start", followed by a "sub file number 2 start", etc as one would reasonably expect? Also, if there's something wrong in your question (like you have two bytes reversed somewhere), you should [edit] and **fix** it — if you want good answers anyway.

Comment: @martineau : Sorry for the typo in my original post, you are right, it has to be sub file number 2 and 3 sections. I edited the first two bytes in the original post as well.

Comment: That's an improvement, but the decoded data still doesn't match the binary data shown at the very beginning of your question. It's also unclear if the data in the log file is in big- or little-endian format. Anyway, to avoid furhter discussion, use the `struct` module as suggested by @Natrix's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `struct` module in the standard library. It provides a function called `unpack`.

> `struct.unpack(format, buffer)`
>
> Unpack from the buffer buffer (presumably packed by `pack(format, ...)`) according to the format string format. The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item. The buffer’s size in bytes must match the size required by the format, as reflected by `calcsize()`.

An important thing is the endianess / byte order of your file. In my post I will assume, your file has always little endian.

```
Character  | Byte order | Size     | Alignment
@            native       native     native
=            native       standard   none
<            little       standard   none
>            big          standard   none
```

This table tells you the format name you need. Here it is `<`.
You can look at the format codes for types at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters.
The first structure, the file header consists first of an 16bit unsigned integer, then 6 bytes of data, a 16bit unsigned integer and then an unsigned byte. So the format code for the file header is `'<H6sBHB'`. So reading the file header could look like this:

```py
from struct import unpack
header = f.read(11)
file_number, date, file_id, file_count = unpack('<H6sHB', header)
```

With `struct.iter_unpack` you can now parse all the subfile headers.

```py
subfile_headers = f.read(7 * file_count)  # One subfile header takes 7 bytes
subfile_iterator = struct.iter_unpack('<HBHH', subfile_headers)
for start, length, data, end in subfile_iterator:
    ...  # do something with the subfile headers
```

I hope this was a little useful, although I did not fully understand your question.
It would be helpful, if you could provide some information about what you want to do with this file.
Also I probably could help you more if you would explain me this part of your question:

> Also, if I write this logic in another file, by passing file as input argument, all the details shall be fetched in a tuple or dict?